# Static select in where

Tags: mysql

Any ideas why this is not working on mysql?

```
SELECT true AS is_valid FROM users WHERE is_valid
```

I need to write it in this way, because i'm using a framework which generates the queries.

but i get

```
Unknown column 'is_valid' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: Any ideas? Why would it work??? What would it do if it worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the alias name in the `where` clause as the query is parsed from right to left. So the alias name of the column is not known once its starts from right resulting in the unknown column error.

From the [MySql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> "A select_expr can be given an alias using AS alias_name. The alias is
>   used as the expression's column name and can be used in GROUP BY,
>   ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses."

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an alias of a `SELECT` expression in the `WHERE` clause because of the `SELECT` query semantics: first it `JOIN`s the tables (does not apply here), then it filters the rows using the conditions from the `WHERE` clause, after that it computes the expressions from the `SELECT` clause and, optional, it creates aliases for some of them. The processing of the `GROUP BY`+`HAVING` follows (if present) then the resulting rows are sorted according to the `ORDER BY` clause and finally the `LIMIT` values (if present) are used to send back to the client only the requested rows.